# Не дает доступ к базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, pdo

В чем ошибка?

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception `PDOException` with message *invalid
>   data source name* in
>   /home/e/e96548p5/e96548p5.beget.tech/public_html/db.php:5 
>   Stack trace:
>    #0 /home/e/e96548p5/e96548p5.beget.tech/public_html/db.php (5):  `PDO->__construct('dbname=e96548p5...', 'e96548p5', 'пароль бд')`
>    #1
>   /home/e/e96548p5/e96548p5.beget.tech/public_html/index.php (3):
>   `include('/home/e/e96548p...')`
>    #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/e/e96548p5/e96548p5.beget.tech/public_html/db.php on line 5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скрипт подключения:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=e96548p5_test;host=localhost';
$user = 'e96548p5';
$password = 'пароль бд';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
?>
```

Comment: Не пробовали dbname и host в строке dsn поменять местами?

Comment: вы уверены что данная бд существует и указанный пользователь имеет к ней доступ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выводится неизвестная ошибка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749890/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Вы там мне на комментарий не ответили.

Answer (score 0):

Пропустили `host=localhost;` в подключении.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e96548p5_test;host=localhost';
```